# Transformation of periodic data prior to PCA?

Tags: pca, data-transformation, nonlinear

Basically I have periodic data (angles from -180 to 180) that I want perform a PCA on. However, since the data is periodic, a change in angle from say 170 to 10 will not be accurately reflected. I was wondering if anybody had a good/reliable way to transform the data without introducing new artifacts from the transformation on the data?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered cyclic encoding?

Transform your angle into two new features -$sin(\theta), cos(\theta)$

It adds the complexity of having two variables instead of one but solves the exact problem you're describing.

Here's another [question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5990/what-is-a-good-way-to-transform-cyclic-ordinal-attributes) about the topic with a good explanation

Comment: I have considered this but the sin/cos transformation are non-linear no? Wouldn't this introduce artefacts into my data/analysis?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by artifacts. Could you elaborate? This transformation uniquely and reversibly maps every point you have to a new point, and it's a pretty common technique.  Is there a specific reason you don't want to try it?

Comment: Based on what I read in this paper "the nonlinearity of
the sine and cosine transformations render it difficult to interpret the results in terms of the underlying observables." from Principal component analysis on a torus: Theory and application
to protein dynamics